# OpenTelemetry Next.js - No http_route label for http_server_duration metrics

Tags: node.js, next.js, prometheus, open-telemetry

I've implemented tracing and metrics on my Next.js app using OpenTelemetry (my implementation is below). The app sends the traces/metrics to my Grafana Agent which then forwards them onto the appropriate data source (e.g. Tempo and Prometheus).

In Prometheus, I am getting 'http_server_duration_*' metrics for my app. However, on those metrics I am not getting a 'http_route' label (or something similar e.g. 'http_target'). I do get a 'http_route' for the same metrics for my .Net apps using OpenTelemtry so I was expecting it for my Next.js app too. In the traces for my Next.js app, I can see 'http.target' and 'http.url' in the Span Attributes, but not 'http.route'. It's probably also worth mentioning that my app does not use express. I believe it is the express Opentelemtry instrumentation that usually adds 'http.route' to the traces (as mentioned here - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/3694).

- So I have two questions please:

1. Is it possible to add the 'http_route' label to the 'http_server_duration_*' metrics for my app by using the requestHook to set custom attributes on the spans (which is then passed onto the metrics)?
2. If the above is not possible, there are any alternatives?

```
const { NodeSDK } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-node');
const { PeriodicExportingMetricReader, ConsoleMetricExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics');
const { OTLPTraceExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-grpc');
const { OTLPMetricExporter } = require('@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-grpc');
const { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } = require('@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node');

const sdk = new NodeSDK({
 traceExporter: new OTLPTraceExporter(),
  metricReader: new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: new OTLPMetricExporter(),
  }),
  instrumentations: [
    getNodeAutoInstrumentations({
      '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fs': {
        enabled: false,
      },
      '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http': {
          // This gives your request spans a more meaningful name than `HTTP GET`
          requestHook: (span, request) => {
            span.updateName( `${request.method} ${request.url || request.path}` );
            // The below is not working
            //span.setAttribute('http.route', request.path);
          },
       },
    }),
  ]

});

sdk.start();
```